# MDADM Array Being Limited to 2.0TB

Tags: ubuntu, software-raid, mdadm, filesystems

I have an MDADM array with four 1TB disks in a RAID5 configuration.
Here's the relevant part of `mdadm --detail /dev/md1`:

```
        Version : 00.90
     Raid Level : raid5
     Array Size : 2929537920 (2793.83 GiB 2999.85 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 976512640 (931.28 GiB 999.95 GB)
   Raid Devices : 4
  Total Devices : 4
Preferred Minor : 1
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent
```

It shows that the array is 2.8TB. Here is `fdisk -l /dev/md1`:

```
Disk /dev/md1: 2999.8 GB, 2999846830080 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 732384480 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 8 * 512 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 65536 bytes / 196608 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xffffffff
Disk /dev/md1 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

fdisk also shows it to be 3TB. However, `df -Th` does not agree:

```
Filesystem    Type    Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md1      ext3    1.8T  1.8T     0 100% /
```

Why does everything show `/dev/md1` to be 3TB but the space is limited to only 2TB?

Other details: Ubuntu 10.10

UPDATE:

`$ tune2fs -l /dev/md1`:

```
tune2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
Filesystem volume name:   <none>
Last mounted on:          <not available>
Filesystem UUID:          1b4e9420-61ee-4ffd-817a-28831f2aeaf2
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype needs_recovery sparse_super large_file
Filesystem flags:         signed_directory_hash
Default mount options:    (none)
Filesystem state:         clean
Errors behavior:          Continue
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Inode count:              122068992
Block count:              488255968
Reserved block count:     24412798
Free blocks:              69746292
Free inodes:              121882953
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
Reserved GDT blocks:      907
Blocks per group:         32768
Fragments per group:      32768
Inodes per group:         8192
Inode blocks per group:   512
RAID stride:              16
RAID stripe width:        32
Filesystem created:       Sun Oct 17 01:14:23 2010
Last mount time:          Mon Dec  6 01:24:31 2010
Last write time:          Mon Dec  6 00:45:41 2010
Mount count:              12
Maximum mount count:      23
Last checked:             Sun Dec  5 20:37:35 2010
Check interval:           15552000 (6 months)
Next check after:         Fri Jun  3 21:37:35 2011
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
First inode:              11
Inode size:               256
Required extra isize:     28
Desired extra isize:      28
Journal inode:            8
First orphan inode:       55550208
Default directory hash:   half_md4
Directory Hash Seed:      2a386fcb-b24f-4f40-bf4c-7c03489b086c
Journal backup:           inode blocks
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add the 4th drive after creating the filesystem?  That could lead to the FS being smaller than the underlying device.

Alternatively, maybe your ext3 has 1k blocks, as this would lead to a 2TB filesystem size limit ([ext3 size limits](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Ext3#Size_limits)).

Please post the output of "sudo tune2fs -l /dev/md1", and look closely at the Block size line.

Comment: I did add the 4th drive after setting everything up with three drives.

Comment: You need to do a "mke2fs" after creating a RAID array for it to have a valid file-system.  If you created a 3 drive RAID-5, did a mke2fs, then added a 4th drive and created a new RAID array with them, the file-system is likely to be quite messed up.  If you added the drive using the software RAID "growing", you just need to "resize2fs /dev/md1" while the system is running to get it to use the additional space.  However, if you re-initialized the array instead of growing it, resize2fs will likely make the data completely unusable.

Comment: I did use `mdadm --grow` so resize2fs worked fine. Thank you.